# How to return an empty singly linked list in Scala?

Tags: scala, singly-linked-list

I am a newcomer in Scala and recently I met a problem when I submitted my Scala solution to the problem (143. Reorder List) in Leetcode.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode(var _x: Int = 0) {
 *   var next: ListNode = null
 *   var x: Int = _x
 * }
 */
object Solution {
    def reorderList(head: ListNode): ListNode = {
        val hd: ListNode = head
        if (head == null || head.next == null || head.next.next == null) head
        // find middle in [1,2,3,4,5]
        else {
            var runner: ListNode = head
            var walker: ListNode = head
            while (runner.next != null && runner.next.next != null) {
                runner = runner.next.next
                walker = walker.next
            }
            val mid: ListNode = walker // 3
            var secondHead: ListNode = mid.next // 4
            mid.next = null // now we have [1,2,3,null]
              // Reverse second part 
            secondHead = reverse(secondHead) // [5,4,null]
              // dummy node link to head
            val dummy: ListNode = new ListNode(0)
            dummy.next = head
              // Connect 
            var firstHead: ListNode = head
            while (secondHead != null) {
                val tmp: ListNode = secondHead.next
                secondHead.next = firstHead.next
                firstHead.next = secondHead
                firstHead = firstHead.next.next
                secondHead = tmp
            }
            dummy.next
        }
    }

    def reverse(head: ListNode): ListNode = {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) head
        else {
            var newHead: ListNode = null
            var curHead: ListNode = head
            while (curHead != null) {
                val tmp: ListNode = curHead.next
                curHead.next = newHead
                newHead = curHead
                curHead = tmp
            }
            newHead
        }    
    }
}
```

But when it comes to the test case of an input of

```
[]
```

which is an empty ListNode, then the output of my Scala code is,

```
null
```

while the expected output is

```
[]
```

Can anyone teach me how to get this correct output?

(There is no Scala solution to this problem in "Discussion" section)

Here's [a link](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/description/)!

Comment: What does `[]` mean in this context? What is an empty `ListNode` that is not a `null` variable of type `ListNode`?

Comment: Oh, so it's a `ListNode` where `x` is `null`?

Comment: `Int` cannot be null.

Comment: @Dima Sure. I’m sorry I mean it’s an empty Singly Linked List whose head is the input parameter of this program.

Comment: I know what you mean. I am just saying, if your list has a head, it cannot be empty, because it'll always contain some int value.

Comment: You might want to use Option and None instead of null in scala.

Comment: The main question is about the definition of `ListNode` can it be changed or not? The way it is defined make this code horrible, would be easy to fix with another definition...

Comment: Try returning Option[ListNode] instead of ListNode

Comment: @zlace this does not work, can you try out my code on https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/description/ please?

Comment: @FredericA. the main problem is how to pass the test case which requires an output like "[]" try out my code https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-list/description/ it's only rejected by one test case.

Comment: I see. I don't know about that website but after seeing just this example, I can tell that there is no way you can claim *any* scala knowledge after doing that kind of exercise... good luck with it

Comment: The problem with the tester on scala is that it checks the answers on the param head which is immutable. The only mutable portion is head.next onwards, thus when head = null this question is unsolvable.

Comment: @zlace exactly! Thanks bro

Comment: @FredericA. You’re right sir, also the test base is not well designed for scala.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

LeetCode has only recently started supporting Scala solutions and there have been a few glitches to work out. This has been one of them.

They've now fixed the problem and I've confirmed that it can be solved (~20 lines of Scala code).

BTW, `[]` is just a language-agnostic way to express empty or non-values so, essentially, there is no difference between `[]` and `null`.